# py2app argv-emulation error

Tags: py2app

I'm trying to build an app using `py2app` but when I do:

```
py2applet csSlates.py --iconfile csSlateCreator.png
```

I dont get the icon in the app and I get this error message:

> error: argv-emulation is not supported for 64-bit executables

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't figured it out already, that icon file needs to be in .icns format.

you can use this utility to convert it:
http://projects.digitalwaters.net/index.php?q=fasticns_download

if you haven't run the --make-setup option you'd need to do that as well.

**py2applet --make-setup csSlates.py --iconfile csSlateCreator.icns**

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem and resolved it by using Python 2.5 rather than 2.7.